# Different prefixes in SIrange

Tags: siunitx

I use the *siunitx* package for typesetting numbers, units and ranges.
When typesetting large ranges of numbers, for example "150 kHz to 8 MHz", I prefer the notation with different prefixes, i.e. "kilo" for the first number and "mega" for the second. However, I have not been able to typeset such a range using the *siunitx* macro `\SIrange`.

So far I have found two possibilities: Simply using "kHz" for both numbers. This leads to the (in my opinion) not very nice format "150 kHz to 8000 kHz", which I want to avoid. 
The only alternative I found was to manually create the two numbers using `\SI`, as illustrated in the following example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
    \SIrange{150}{8000}{\kilo\hertz}

    \SI{150}{\kilo\hertz} to \SI{8}{\mega\hertz}    
\end{document}
```

Is there any way to get an output similar to the second version (separate `\SI`'s), but using `\SIrange` ? This would be nice, as it allows to globally change e.g. the range phrase ("to") and has a consistent spacing.

Comment: Would this be ok? `\SIrange[scientific-notation = engineering,exponent-to-prefix = true, round-mode=figures]{150}{8000}{\kilo\hertz}`. You can define that globally as well.

Comment: The `exponent-to-prefix` option is somehow what I'm looking for. Though I am not 100% happy with the "8.0 MHz". Especially if one needs a precision of 3 (e.g. for "125 kHz"), it would be "8.00 MHz" which isn't really what I want.

Comment: @hbaderts You can also give the option `zero-decimal-to-integer` to make sure it is displayed as `8 MHz` rather than `8.0 MHz` or `8.00 MHz`.

Comment: Indeed, your two comments combined (+ `round-precision=3`) gives the desired results! Not very short, but exactly what I need. Thanks for your help @LaRiFaRi and @nordev. Does anybody of you want to post this as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This answer got outdated with later versions of `siunitx`. Version 2015/01/21 v2.6e was used here.**

---

I think the shortest form for what you want would be:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{%
    ,exponent-to-prefix = true
    ,zero-decimal-to-integer
    }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{l}
            \SIrange[scientific-notation = engineering]{150}{8000}{\kilo\hertz}\\
            \SIrange[scientific-notation = engineering]{100}{50000}{\tesla}\\
            \num{1234.1245345}
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

You have to set the scientific notation locally in order not to change the normal numbers. You will have to decide, which options can be taken globally and which don't.

[image]

Comment: Your code did not produce these texts

Comment: @RubemPacelli I have just tested this very code on Overleaf and it looked just like my screenshot.

Comment: That is weird. I just copied and paste your code on Overleaf and it didn't produce the same result. Take a look: https://ibb.co/rZYhvFg

Comment: ah ok, you are right. My overleaf was set to tex-live 2014... :-)
So there was a change between siuntix 2015/01/21 v2.6e which I was using here and 2022-06-07 v3.1.3 which I have now. Sorry for the confusion.