# Numberless range with different prefixes using siunitx?

Tags: siunitx, sirange

I'm using the siunitx package in the [Masters/Doctoral Thesis](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis) template and I'd like to write something along the lines of **"on timescales of μs-s"** but am as yet unable to replicate this using the \SIrange function.

Can anyone help, or direct me to a previously given answer if I've missed one? I have found an answer to [different prefixes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261911/different-prefixes-in-sirange) but not with numberless units.

Thanks

Comment: Why not write it by hand: `\si{\u\s}\textendash\si{\s}`?

Comment: Wow, I was certainly overthinking that! Can you tell I'm new to this? Thanks for the fast and helpful response!

Comment: `\SIrange` is for a range of numbers, not a range of units, so this isn't what it's intended for. You can also use `--` instead of `\textendash` by the way, `\si{\micro\s}--\si{\s}`.  (@Bernard, would you consider writing an answer?)